# GoogleTransport cannot be resolved

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-url-shortener

I am trying to use the Google URL shortener API in my Spring MVC application. I have downloaded the Google API java client zip and added all the jars to my project build path and tried to run a sample code.

> 

```
// setup up the HTTP transport
    HttpTransport transport = GoogleTransport.create();
    // add default headers
    GoogleHeaders defaultHeaders = new GoogleHeaders();
    transport.defaultHeaders = defaultHeaders;
    transport.defaultHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    transport.addParser(new JsonCParser());
    // build the HTTP GET request and URL

    GenericData data = new GenericData();
    data.put("longUrl", "http://www.google.com/");

    JsonHttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent();
    content.data = data;

    HttpRequest request = transport.buildPostRequest();
    request.content = content;
    request.setUrl(GOOGL_URL);
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        JSONObject json = request.execute().parseAs(JSONObject.class);      
    } catch (IOException e) {           
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block                                
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the problem is it cannot resolve GoogleTransport. I just cant find it in any jar. Can some one please point me to where I can find it. I have no idea whats wrong and constant googling has led me nowhere. And yes, I cannot use maven, downloaded jars are the only option that i have :( . Please any help would be great.

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I'm having the same now. Please help.

Comment: nops , dint get much response here, and was on a deadline so moved on to bitly. Sorry :(